# How many sounds can be played at a time on iOS - AVAudioPlayer vs. AVAudioEngine & AVAudioPlayerNode

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudioplayernode

I have an application in which there is a set of about 50 sounds, which range in length from about 300 ms to about 4 seconds. Various combinations of sounds need to be played at precise times (up to 10 of them can be triggered at once). Some sounds need to be repeated at intervals as short as 100 ms.

I've implemented this is as a two dimensional array of AVAudioPlayers, all of which are loaded with sounds at application launch. There are several players for each sound, to accommodate rapidly repeating sounds. The players for a particular sound are reused in strict rotation. When a new sound is scheduled, the oldest player for that sound is stopped and its current time is set to 0, so the sound will repeat from the start, the next time it's scheduled using player.play(atTime:). There's a thread that schedules new sets of sounds about 300 ms before they are to be played.

It all works quite nicely, up to a point that varies with the device. Eventually, as sounds are played more rapidly, and/or more simultaneous sounds are scheduled, some sounds will refuse to play.

I'm contemplating switching to AVAudioEngine and AVAudioPlayerNodes, using a mixer node. Does anyone know if that approach is likely to handle more simultaneous sounds? My guess is that both approaches translate into a rather similar set of CoreAudio functions, but I haven't actually written the code to test that hypothesis - before I do that, I'm hoping that someone else may have explored this issue before me. I've been deep into CoreAudio before, and I'm hoping to be able to use these handy high-level functions instead!

Also, does anyone know of a way to trigger a closure when a sound initiates? The documented functionality allows for a callback closure, but the only way I've been able to trigger events when the sounds start, is to create a high quality of service queue for DispatchQueue. Unfortunately, depending on the system load, queued events may be executed at times that vary from the scheduled times by up to about 50 ms, which is not quite as precise as I'd prefer to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AVAudioEngine with AVAudioPlayersNodes provides much better performance, albeit at the cost of a bit of code complexity. I was able to easily increase the playback rate by a factor of five, with better buffer control.

The main drawback in switching to this approach was that Apple's documentation is less than stellar. A few additions to Apple's documentation would have made this task a LOT easier:

Mixer nodes are documented as being able to convert sample rates and channel counts, so I attempted to configure audioEngine.mainMixerNode to convert mono buffers to the output node's settings. Setting the main mixer node's output to the output node's format appeared to be accepted, but threw opaque errors at run time that complained about channel count mismatches.

It appears that the main mixer node is not actually a fully functional mixer node. To get this to work, I had to insert another mixer node that performed the channel conversion, and connect it to the main mixer node. If Apple's documentation had actually mentioned this, it would have saved me a lot of experimentation.

Also, just scheduling a buffer does not cause anything to play. You need to call play() on the player node before anything will happen. Apple's documentation is confusing here - it says that calling play() with no arguments will cause playback to occur immediately, which wasn't what I wanted. It took some experimentation to determine that play() just tells the player node to wake up, and that scheduled buffers will actually be played at the scheduled time, rather than immediately.

It would have been enormously helpful if Apple had provided more than the auto-generated class documentation. A bit of human-generated documentation would have saved me an awful lot of frustrating experimentation.

Chris Adamson's well-written "Learning Core Audio" was very helpful when I was working with Core Audio - it's a shame that the newer AVAudioEngine functionality isn't documented nearly as well.